# jQuery: .click(function(){(element),collapse('show',false) only disables after document click trigger fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

on first run if you click the body anywhere it activates the collapse element. I want it to only collapse the accordion on click not show it. right now it will deactivate only after it is hidden once

**HTML**

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="accordion" style="z-index:9999">
            <div class="panel contact-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" role="tab" id="headingTwo" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="color:#fff!important;">    <span><h5 style="margin-bottom:0!important;"><i class="fa fa-envelope">&nbsp;</i>Your Title here</h5></span>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Message</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Message Content Here"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="human" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Are You <strong><u>Human</u>?</strong>

                                </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input id="field_human" class="field_human" type="checkbox" name="human" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                                    <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block btn-lg">Send</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

---

```
.row > p{
    padding:2%;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:#eee;
}
.accordion {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:-2.1%;
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
.accordion label {
    color:#fff;
}
.accordion input {
    border-radius:0;
}
.panel-heading, .panel-heading:hover, .panel-heading:focus, .panel-heading.focus, .panel-heading:active, .panel-heading.active {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #c9302c;
    border-color: #ac2925;
    outline:none;
}
.accordion-toggle {
    text-align:center;
}
.accordion-toggle span:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
    content:"\f077";
    color: white;
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-top:-4.8%;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:120%;
}
.accordion-toggle .collapsed span:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content:"\f078";
}
.contact-panel {
    border-radius:0;
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border-color: #d43f3a;
}
.btn-dark {
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.btn-dark:hover, .btn-dark:focus, .btn-dark:active, .btn-dark.active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

**JavaScript**

---

```
//return all check-boxes and unchecked
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

//check all check all input elements to see if they are check-boxes
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
//If the input is a check-box run script else skip over
    if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
    //If it is a check-box ensure the box is unchecked
    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
//define Element by ID and create variable
    var $checked = $('#field_human');

//define default state for attribute before handler function trigger
$("#submit").attr("disabled", !$checked.checked)
//On element handler trigger define function to execute each time handler is triggered
$checked.click(function () {
    //State to define instance on method 
    if ($checked.prop('checked')) {
        //return true
        //remove element attribute state 'disabled'
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        //return false
        //set element attribute state 'disabled'
        $("#submit").attr("disabled", !$checked.checked);
    }
    //return to ready-state to wait for handler to trigger again
    return;
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("document.click");

    // stop document click event from firing collapse('show') event
});

//On Element jQuery mouseenter Event '.accordion' show '#collapseOne'
$('.accordion').on('mouseenter', function () {
    //Fire the Event
    $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show');
    return false; //Same as 'e.preventDefault();'
});

$('.accordion').on('click', function (e) {
    //Parent and Siblings => show (override document Click event)
    $(this + siblings).collapse('hide', false);
    //stop the code from bubbling up
    e.preventDefault();
});

//Document Click Event hide '#collapseTwo'
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    // Target => collapse('hide').collapse('toggle')
 if($('#collapseTwo').hasClass('in') && $(e.target).closest('.form-horizontal').length==0) {
         $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');
    }
    //stop the code from bubbling up
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

});
```

---

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/blayderunner123/3pect72z/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add `preventDefault()` on the document on click trigger because it will break the external links from working. As such, I removed the prevent default and all my links to include `easyScroll()` and external links all work now. See code below for details:

```
//return all check-boxes and unchecked
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

//check all check all input elements to see if they are check-boxes
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
{
    //If the input is a check-box run script else skip over
    if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
    {
        //If it is a check-box ensure the box is unchecked
        checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    //define Element by ID and create variable
    var $checked = $('#field_human');

    //define default state for attribute before handler function trigger
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", !$checked.checked)
    //On element handler trigger define function to execute each time handler is triggered
    $checked.click(function()
    {
        //State to define instance on method 
        if ($checked.prop('checked'))
        {
            //return true
            //remove element attribute state 'disabled'
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        else
        {
            //return false
            //set element attribute state 'disabled'
            $("#submit").attr("disabled",!$checked.checked);
        }
        //return to ready-state to wait for handler to trigger again
        return;
    });

    /*$(document).on('click',function(e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("document.click");

        // stop document click event from firing collapse('show') event
    });*/

    //On Element jQuery mouseenter Event '.accordion' show '#collapseOne'
    $('.accordion').on('mouseenter', function()
    {
        //Fire the Event
        $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show');
        return false; //Same as 'e.preventDefault();'
    });

    $('.accordion').on('click', function(e)
    {
        //Parent and Siblings => show (override document Click event)
        $(this + siblings).collapse('hide', false);
        //stop the code from bubbling up
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //Document Click Event hide '#collapseTwo'
    $(document).on('click', function(e)
    {
        // Target => collapse('hide').collapse('toggle')
        if($('#collapseTwo').hasClass('in') && $(e.target).closest('.form-horizontal').length==0)
        {
            $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');
        }
        //stop the code from bubbling up
        e.stopPropagation();
        //e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

You can see it working on my site at **[Soldier-up Designs](https://soldierupdesigns.com)**

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the collapse element has class `in` before hiding

```
 $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        // Target => collapse('hide')
         if($('#collapseTwo').hasClass('in') && $(e.target).closest('.form-horizontal').length==0) {
             $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide');
        }
        //stop the code from bubbling up
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3pect72z/5/)

Comment: You are so awesome never thought to use "in" do you have any documentation so I can read up on this? but it is right

Comment: See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage) it says `.collapse.in shows the content`

Comment: how do I keep the accordion open when I click the input section? now that broke

Comment: Ok, I have updated the fiddle. What am doing is checking whether the clicked section has a parent with `.form-horizontal` class and then accordingly toggling.

Comment: this works now... did you change anything? I am wondering if you did not change anything if it is a browser specific thing. please let mer know if you updated fiddle... Thanks.

Comment: I have changed the condition. If you look now I am checking two things, one if `collapseTwo` has class `in` and if the the clicked element has a parent form (` $(e.target).closest('.form-horizontal').length==0`)

Answer (score 0):

Just comment `$('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide', true);` this line will solved your issue.

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
        // Target => collapse('hide')
       // $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide', true); //commented this line.
        //stop the code from bubbling up
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/3pect72z/1/)

**Edit:**

Add following in your jQuery part will solved your issue:

```
$('#collapseTwo').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide', true);
    });
```

Updated [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/3pect72z/2/)

Check following if condition:

```
if ($('#collapseTwo').is(':visible'))
   {
    $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide', true);
   }
```

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/3pect72z/4/)

Comment: stand by let me check I think you are right. I did this before but could not remember

Comment: Ok that is the first part but I want it to also collapse the accordion on document click just not reactivate it

Comment: Your at 50% so far. I needed that line there to collapse the accordion on document click just not activate it on click does this make sense?

Comment: @blayderunner123 check my edited answer. I think that is what u need.

Comment: Your at 75% try to trigger accordion element to hide on document click after it is opened

Comment: document click = hide collapse element and on .accordion mouseenter = show element

Comment: Still hides on input:focus

Comment: @ketan: I am not going to down vote you as your answer is not wrong. However, it is not complete either. The issue is as anpsmn pointed out was to check if the element had 'in'  before hiding the element.  See above. Thank you for all your help and the issue is resolved.